# Proving Openness of a Set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am taking real analysis for the first time, and I am still having trouble formulating proofs for showing that a set is open. Suppose for $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, I have the set 
$$C=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n | d(x,y)<1 \ \text{for some} \ y\in B\}.$$

I want to show that C is open.
Here is what I have so far:

C is open if for each $x\in C$ there exists an $\epsilon >0$ such that $D(x,\epsilon) \subset C$. 
So take any arbitrary point $x\in C.$ Since $d(x,y)<1$ strictly, we can always find an $\epsilon$ such that $d(x+\epsilon, y) <1$. But how do you formalize this proof? Do I have to offer up a candidate for epsilon? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're off to a good start. You've chosen $x \in C$ and want to find $\epsilon>0$ such that $D(x,\epsilon) \subset C$. You've also noted that there exists $y \in B$ such that $d(x,y)<1$. Note that $C$ consists of *every* point that is within distance $1$ of a point in $B$. Let's try and choose $D(x,\epsilon)$ so that every point in $D(x,\epsilon)$ is strictly less than distance $1$ away from $y$ (and thus is in $C$ by definition).

Since $x$ is *strictly less* than distance $1$ from $y$, you should be able to move a small distance away from $x$ and still be strictly less than distance $1$ away from $y$. To make this precise, let $d=d(x,y)<1$. Choose $z\in D(x,\epsilon)$ ($\epsilon$ to be determined). Then by the triangle inequality, $d(z,y) \leq d(z,x)+d(x,y) <\epsilon+d$. How can you choose $\epsilon$ to ensure $\epsilon+d \leq 1$?

Another option (if you know that balls $D(x,\epsilon)$ are open and that the union of open sets is open) is to try writing $C$ as a union of open balls centered at points in $B$.

Also note it doesn't make sense to write $x+\epsilon$ as you have, since $\epsilon$ is a real number but $x$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n$.